# Tips for template systems

Tags: templates

i am wondering how i can create functional template system, something like smarty.
I dont want to use ready made template systems because they slow down page.
I want  to create template system where i can add in certain pages a new JS code or new stylesheet or even remove the sidebar.
I think i could get that result by using output buffering.

Answer (score 6):

Template systems are complex beasts. Don't try to reinvent the wheel, just use something there already exists.

If you feel smarty is too heavy weight, look for something that is a bit lighter and that will fit your needs better. Writing and maintaining your own will take far more time and effort.

Comment: well i dont want to create anything complex i just want to create template system where i can freely manipulate with sidebars (hide sidebars or replace sidebar content).

Comment: Look at jQuery and what it has to offer. There are many plugins that can do what you are looking for.